# JQuery click event not working correctly after class change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JQuery script similar to this:

```
$('.follow_link').click(function(){
  // Do some stuff
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("unfollow_link");
});

$('.unfollow_link').click(function(){
  // Do some stuff
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("follow_link");
});
```

My problem is that after I change the class the link is still refering to it's old class' click event.
Is there a way of rebinding? Or am I doing this a bad way?

Comment: did you try the 'live' binding?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this, both functions in 1:

```
$('.unfollow_link, .follow_link').live("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("follow_link unfollow_link");
});
```

See [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), and the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

> **.toggleClass( className )**
>   classNameOne or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.

**Edit for new jQuery versions 1.6.4+**

Since the `live` function does not exists anymore, here is a replacement:

```
$('body').on("click", '.unfollow_link, .follow_link', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("follow_link unfollow_link");
});
```

Comment: If you're going to select all the elements, you may as well use `click`...  `live` isn't necessary with this code and is inefficient.

Comment: "Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of .live()" read more: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live` does not work for me, nothing happens on click!

Comment: This post is pretty old and LIVE does not exists anymore. The new way to do it is a delegate. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that jQuery works by selecting elements (that's what `$('.follow_link')` does) and then binding an event handler to *those* elements (that's what `.click*function(){` does).  It doesn't matter if the class changes.

Javascript has a feature called event bubbling. This means that ancestor elements are notified of events on their descendants.  This means that you can test selectors when the event occurs, rather than on document ready.

jQuery makes this easy with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.follow_link', function(){
  // Do some stuff
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("unfollow_link");
}).on('click', '.unfollow_link', function(){
  // Do some stuff
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("follow_link");
});
```

Note that this function was introduced in jQuery 1.7. For compatibility with previous versions, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to give each of the links a third class that designates that they are part of a group. Something like `a_link`:

```
$('.a_link').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('follow_link unfollow_link');
});
```

Comment: I suspect this will work but @Niels example looks a little cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I just had this issue even if the `on()` function and still have the issue on JQuery 1.10,

Actually I resolved the problem by replacing:

```
$('.unfollow_link, .follow_link').live("click", function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("follow_link unfollow_link");
});
```

By

```
$(document).on('click','.unfollow_link, .follow_link', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("follow_link unfollow_link");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
$('.follow_link, .unfollow_link').click(function() {
    newclass = $(this).hasClass('follow_link') ? 'unfollow_link' : 'follow_link';
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(newclass)
});
```

edit: Niels' solution is much nicer.