# JQuery: add class to element - cannot use this class for selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass

I have the following problem: in order to mark an element during different situation I want to add a class to the element:

```
jQuery('#menu-item-41 a').addClass('newsbox-closed1');
```

Later I want to do some funny staff when the element with this class is clicked - so far it works fine:

```
jQuery('.newsbox-closed1').click(function(){
      jQuery('#newsbox').css('display', 'block');
      jQuery(this).css('background-color', '#FF33AB').removeClass('newsbox-closed1').addClass('news-open');
 });
```

Until now everything is just fine. The element gets the class "news-open" andf the newsbox appears. But then the following does not work anymore:

```
jQuery('.news-open').click(function(){
  alert('JUCVJU');
  jQuery(this).removeClass('news-open').addClass('newsbox-closed2');
  jQuery('#newsbox').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Idea: when someone clicks on the same link again, the newsbox should disappear and the link gets a new class. This does not work - the class "new-open" is not removed, the alertbox is not shown, nothing.
Additionally the following work half the way - it is a close button on the newsbox:

```
jQuery('#close').click(function(){
  jQuery('#newsbox').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.news-open').removeClass('news-offen').addClass('newsbox-closed2')
});
```

The element with id "newsbox" disappears but the second part has no effect. The class remains of this element. I get no error messages, nothing... does anyone has an idea what can cause this?

Best,
Tobias

Comment: Putting this in jsFiddle would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding class at runtime. Change

```
jQuery('.news-open').click(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery('.news-open').on('click',(function(){
```

Above is for JQuery >=1.7

For JQuery <1.7, use

```
jQuery('.news-open').live('click',function(){
```

live and on in JQuery work for elements created at runtime too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to delegate your event handler, since you're changing classes after the document loads. Try replacing

```
jQuery('.news-open').click(function(){
```

with

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.news-open', function(){
```

If you can make that more specific than `document`, though, you should. Delegate your event to the closest container of `.news-open` that you can for optimal efficiency.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!!!

To bring it to the point for everybody else facing similar problems my working code looks the following:

```
jQuery('#menu-item-41').on('click', '.news-open', (function(){
  alert('JUCVJU');
  jQuery(this).removeClass('news-open').addClass('newsbox-closed2');
  jQuery('#newsbox').css('display', 'none');
}));
```

The id "menu-item-41" is the id of the container which surrounds my element with class "news-open". Now I get the alert box when I click again on the further re-classed element and the newsbox disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar problem: on clicking a link, I do an animation to show a hidden div, and add `'.hideMe'` classes to the rest of the layout so that a click anywhere off the revealed div will hide it again.  `'.hideMe'` cannot be selected by jQuery since it is not present on page load.  Solved by chaining together two `.on()` methods with delegation, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261148

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#link', function() {
  $('div').addClass('.hideMe').animate(); // animation code here
  $('#newdiv').show();
}).on('click', '.hideme', function() {
  $('div').removeClass('.hideMe').animate(); // animation code here
  $('#newdiv').hide();
});
```

This is jQuery 1.10.x.