# jQuery selectors not working with added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a php/jQuery store and have run into the following problem:
I have a few div boxes as articles and as soon as a box is clicked, it is moved into the shopping cart and therefore has to become inactive.

That's my code so far:

```
 $( ".artbox" ).not( ".inactive" ).on('click', function(){      
    $(this).addClass("inactive");
    $(this).find("#artbox").addClass("inactive")
})
```

It adds the class .inactive to two div objects, which are positioned inside each other. The rest of this function is left out here to keep it short. The problem is that while the according styles for .inactive are applied, I can still click on the box again and again and the function will be called again and again (although I have added the .not() selector) which results in having this specific article in the shopping cart multiple times - and this is what I would like to prevent. If I reload the page manually everything is fine and this

```
$( ".artbox.inactive" ).on('click', function(){
        $(this).effect( "shake", {distance:1});
})
```

works, too (it doesn't for the items added without reloading).
But I am looking for a solution that works without reloading because I am displaying a popup window with a sucess message after the item was added to the cart.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8o2dLnv/)

I've tried this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202186/2842292 but unfortunatly can't get it to work in my example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fail to see why this question was tagged PHP when the question is about jQuery.  Removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventbinding happens on page load, so you should build the logic in the function:

```
$( ".artbox" ).on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("inactive")) {
        $(this).effect( "shake", {distance:1});
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(this).find("#artbox").addClass("inactive");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:

1. You unregister the event listener upon the click. 
   You can do it adding this to the event listener: `$(this).unbind();`,
2. You add an additional check at the very top of the listener:
   `if($(this).hasClass("inactive")) return;`

Then if it even runs, it will quit and will not do the job.